# How do I convert ASCII decimals to a string in C#. This is the code I have so far:

Tags: c#

This is What that I have Tried.Please Suggest me How to convert Assci code into character.

```
 class Decryption
        {
            static void Main()
            {
                string file = @"C:\Users\Me\OneDrive\CSharpProgramming\CipherText.txt";

                string text = File.ReadAllText(file);

                // displaying the contents of the file being read from...
                Console.WriteLine("  Encrypted Text: \n\n{0}", text);

                foreach (char c in text)
                {

                    int ASCIIValues = (char)c - 4;
                    Console.Write(ASCIIValues);

                }

                Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this

```
int ascii = 50;
    char b = (char)ascii;
```

try this

```
int[] arr;
for(i<n)
{
string p += (char)arr[i]+4;
}
```

Comment: No that's not it. Basically the int ASCIIValues = (char)c - 4; converts the string text which stores the input file into ASCII decimals and takes away 4. After it's taken away 4 from the ASCII decimals, I need them to convert back to string.